# Maintain a reference to a struct or other way to refactor this code?

Tags: c#, reference, refactoring

I have this code:

```
BigInteger lhs = new BigInteger(0);
BigInteger rhs = new BigInteger(0);

bool isLeftHandSide = true;

for (int i = 0; i < txtResult.Text.Length; i++)
{
    char currentCharacter = txtResult.Text[i];

    if (char.IsNumber(currentCharacter))
    {
        char currentCharacter = txtResult.Text[i];

        if (isLeftHandSide)
        {
            lhs += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
        }
        else
        {
            rhs += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to instead store a reference to the current side so that I could just manipulate that variable instead and get rid of the if and else statements. I'd like to be able to do this without using unsafe code contexts.

Something like replacing this:

```
if (isLeftHandSide)
{
    lhs += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
}
else
{
    rhs += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
}
```

With this:

```
currentSide += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
```

Where currentSide is a reference to either lhs or rhs. Because they are structs I'm not sure how to keep a reference to it rather than just copying the data.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to add context for the method and the loop.

Comment: Can you put in more context for the code fragments?

Comment: Added some more context.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.  What sort of object reference are you trying to store?

Comment: Trying to store a reference to a `BigInteger`. I guess a possible solution is to wrap it in a container class and make it public to get rid of the if statements.

Comment: Capture it in a lambda.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the variable you want in a lambda, something like this:

```
Action<int> addToCurrentSide;

BigInteger lhs = new BigInteger(0);
BigInteger rhs = new BigInteger(0);

addToCurrentSide = x => lhs += x;

for (int i = 0; i < txtResult.Text.Length; i++)
{
    char currentCharacter = txtResult.Text[i];

    if (char.IsNumber(currentCharacter))
    {
        char currentCharacter = txtResult.Text[i];

        addToCurrentSide((int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter));
    }
}
```

and then to switch sides you just reassign `addToCurrentSide` thus:

```
addToCurrentSide = x => rhs += x;
```

Comment: The `if` is still there, you just described it in text. `addToCurrentSide = isLeftHandSide ? x => lhs += x : x => rhs += x;`

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a wrapper class to add an extra layer of indirection.  (I find this class useful on occasion, I keep it around as a utility class.)

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
BigInteger lhs = new BigInteger(0);
BigInteger rhs = new BigInteger(0);
Wrapper<BigInteger> currentSide = new Wrapper<BigInteger>();

currentSide.Value = lhs;

for (int i = 0; i < txtResult.Text.Length; i++)
{
    char currentCharacter = txtResult.Text[i];

    if (char.IsNumber(currentCharacter))
    {
        currentSide.Value += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, [_"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection"_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). I think this one is more direct than a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can not totally remove the `if` but you can pull it out of the loop:

```
bool isLeftHandSide = true;

if (isLeftHandSide)
   lhs = NewMethod(lhs, txtResult.Text);
else
   rhs = NewMethod(rhs, txtResult.Text);
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `if`.  See my answer.

Comment: @AndrewCooper You only eliminated the `if` because the boolean value was hard coded to `true`.  If it wasn't known until runtime then you would need the same `if` statement.  Through the same reasoning, Henk's refactor could remove the `if` and hardcode the use of `lhs` instead of `rhs` as you have if he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that,

```
var isLeftHandSide = true;
var currentSide = new BigInteger(0);

for (int i = 0; i < txtResult.Text.Length; i++)
{
    char currentCharacter = txtResult.Text[i];
    if (char.IsNumber(currentCharacter))
        currentSide += (int)char.GetNumericValue(currentCharacter);
}

if (isLeftHandSide)
    // lhs = currentSide;
else
    // rhs = currentSide;
```